# Illustrator: which settings to design a logo for print

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-production, color-spaces, document-setup

What settings should I use when creating a document for logo printing? Looking to achieve the best quality for my logo design.

Comment: Illustrator has a "Print Document" preset in most versions, from at least CS4 and later.  Choose that preset when you create a new document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not really matter, the settings in the dialog have no effect on quality of your output if your logo is all vector as it should. The only thing that might adversely affect your quality is the raster effects setting, which you carank up later anyway.

There is just no quality metric in the dialog.

Comment: and what file type should I use to get the best quality for printing sir?

Comment: @creator depends on what you print with.

Comment: what do you mean? sorry (newbie)

Comment: @creator well, different printers operate differently, and how you package a file depends on where its used. So a file suitable for embedding and printing in say Word or latex is different from a file you would send a offset print. You would store the original logo in atleast 2 separate ai files, one for cmyk and one for RGB use. For Word you would say 2 hallelujahs and pray for divine intervention, for latex you use eps and for the offset printer you would send a suitable version of PDF-X that they can handle.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new document for print, make sure the 'Color Mode' is set to 'CMYK' and 'Raster Effects' to 'High (300ppi)'. Normally these should be the default settings in AI's 'New Document' panel.

Comment: and what file type should I use to get the best quality for printing sir?

Comment: Save your document in AI format.